# What is the difference between these noun clauses?

Tags: grammar, word-order, clauses, prepositional-phrases

This comes from an exercise in one of Betty Azar's books.

Do you know **how many minutes there are in 24 hours**?

Do you know **what the distance between the Earth and the Moon is**?

The question is, why can I end the second sentence with "is" but not the first one with "are"?

Comment: Should I just delete and repost over there? I didn't realize they were separate sites.

Comment: Those sentences came out of a Betty Azar book??? The first is unnatural at best (*"Do you know how many minutes **there** are...*), and the second is bad grammar (*Do you know **what** the distance between the **Earth** and the moon is?"*). You can't ask how far a distance is.

Comment: @gotube Why did you capitalize the Earth and not the moon? By the way, you are right about this example.

Comment: @gotube Then replace "how far" with "how long." Why the necessary difference in construction? In other words, why can't I say "Do you know how many minutes in an hour are?" How is this grammatically different from "Do you how long the distance from here to the Moon is?" I also don't think there's anything "unnatural" or ungrammatical about removing "there" from these types of questions.

Thanks again.

Comment: For my last point I mean removing "there" from questions like, "How many people are in the house?" I understand it's necessary in "Do you know how many minutes in an hour **there** are?" but I don't understand why.

Comment: @SheepKeep If I replace your example sentences with my suggestions above, do you still have the same question about "is" and "are"? If so, I can try and answer that, but we can't answer questions about sentences that don't make sense.

Comment: @gotube I think sometimes looking at sentences with errors in them can definitely be instructive. I think part of the difference between these sentences has to do with the answers to these questions - one requires the use of dummy pronoun "there" but the other doesn't. I suspect this explains my original question but I'm still struggling to see exactly how.

Comment: @SheepKeep Sentences with errors are sometimes great for learning, but not if what you want to learn is in a different part of the sentence, and the error prevents applying the rules of grammar. Your original question is about how to end sentences with "is" or "are", so I only want to address that. If you can agree on some good sentences to talk about, then we (at least I) can try and answer. So yes or no, does your question work with my suggested sentences instead of yours?

Comment: @gotube 1a) Do you know how many minutes are in a day? (CORRECT)
1b) Do you know how many minutes in a day are? (INCORRECT)
1c) Do you know how many minutes there are in a day? (CORRECT)
1d) Do you know how many minutes in a day there are? (CORRECT)
2a) Do you know how long the distance between the Earth and the Moon is? (CORRECT)
The question is why is 2a correct but 1b wrong.

Comment: @SheepKeep 1d and 2a are incorrect. 2a) corrected is: "Do you know what the distance... is?" Can we use that instead?

Comment: @gotube Do you have a reference for why 1d is incorrect? And now I'm afraid I've lost the thread - "use that" for what? My question again is why 1b is incorrect but 2a is right.

Comment: @SheepKeep From my answer below, you might be able to see why 1d is incorrect. If not, lemme know :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule here about "ending sentences with is/are". There *is* a rule about moving interrogative pronouns (wh-questions) to the front of a sentence, and sometimes that leaves the verb ("is/are" in your examples) at the end of the sentence.

In your examples, the difference is in the structures of the two noun clauses after "Do you know...".

The deep structure of the first noun clause is:

***subject + verb + subject complement + adverbial***

Step A) "*[there] + [are] + [60 minutes] + [in 24 hours]*"

The question is about "60 minutes", so we replace that section with a wh-question:

Step B) "*[there] [are] **[how many minutes]** [in 24 hours]*"

As with all interrogative pronouns, we move the wh-question to the front of the clause:

Step C) "***[how many minutes]** [there] [are] [in 24 hours]*"

Which gives, "Do you know how many minutes there are in 24 hours?"

---

With the second, the deep structure is:

***subject + verb + subject complement***

Step A) *[the distance between the Earth and the Moon] + [is] + [400,000 km]*

We are asking the question about the 400,000 km, so we replace that with a wh-question:

Step B) *[the distance between the Earth and the Moon] [is] **[what]***

Finally, we move the wh-question to the front of the clause:

Step C) ***[what]** [the distance between the Earth and the Moon] [is]*

Which gives, "Do you know what the distance between the Earth and the Moon is?"